# is there any way to name each entity in dxf file?

Tags: drawing, solidworks, dxf

I want to highlight each line or arc at specific time. Example If mobile design is displayed, I want to highlight only screen dimension to be highlighted one side after the other.
If any identifier/unique code field is present in dxf file which I can refer/address each entity?
or should I consider different file format to achieve same.

Answer (score 2):

The [entity handle](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACDMAC/2016/FRA/?guid=GUID-30C33AF6-4BE3-4334-96BD-F929040C31D3) (DXF group 5) is unique and persistent throughout the life of the entity, as such, this may be used to uniquely identify/address an entity within a drawing database.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer (entity **handle**), you can make use of [Extended Entity Data](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesDXF/WS1a9193826455f5ff18cb41610ec0a2e719-7943.htm). You decide what information you want to attach to each entity. This is saved with the DXF file and you can access it later.

To quote:

> If an entity contains extended data, it follows the entity's normal definition data. The group codes `1000` through `1071` describe extended data.